# Android: Apply skin tone to emoji in TextView

Tags: android, textview, emoji

I am trying to set a fixed text on a TextView. The text contains an emoji. Here's what I have so far:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Welcome to Earth &#128075;" />
```

The TextView above returns the text below:

> Welcome to Earth

I want the emoji to have a dark skin tone. Basically, I want the text to look like this:

> Welcome to Earth

Is there a prefix or suffix I can add to the emoji's unicode to change the skin tone?
If not, how do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a couple of skin-tone codes [here](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_emoji_skin_tones.asp). All I had to do was to append them to my emoji unicode. Here's an illustration:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Welcome to Earth &#128075;&#127998;" />
```

This returns:

> Welcome to Earth